# GDAL scripts not found in QGIS 3 on OSX

Tags: qgis, gdal, osx

I installed QGIS 3, and tried to execute tools like "sieve" "merge" and "polygonize". All of them gave me the error message:

```
GDAL command output: /bin/sh: (scriptname).py: command not found
```

I found the scripts in both `/Username/miniconda3/bin` and `/Username/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/GDAL-2.2.2-py3.6-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg-info/scripts`.

Checking env in Terminal shows that `miniconda3/bin` is in the path:

`PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin://Users/Username/miniconda3/bin`

What could be causing the failure of executing those scripts?

Comment: Please edit your question and specify how you installed QGIS 3.  Note you can't use anaconda python with the KyngChaos QGIS3 package - http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Mac-QGIS-3-amp-Python-3-td5358083.html

Comment: I did install the conda python 3.6, and then installed GDAL and QGIS3 using the KyngChaos packages downloaded from https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html.

Comment: If I can't use conda python with QGIS3, should I install the python.org python and then re-install QGIS3? What should I do with the conda python?

Comment: I think that QGIS uses it's own isolated python/gdal environment and does not look to any other installations. So it seems like it is a problem within QGIS 3. I have seen some other problems with QGIS 3. It was just released and the release note (http://blog.qgis.org/2018/02/23/qgis-3-0-girona-is-released/) says that "we do not expect it to be as reliable as the 2.18 LTR just yet". I'd uninstall 3 and go back to 2.18.

Comment: @jdbcode QGIS doesn't use "it's own isolated python/gdal environment and does not look to any other installations.". Nor is it a problem with QGIS 3.0 per se.  It's a problem of binary compatibility.  QGIS 3.0 was built against python.org Python 3.6 and requires that to be installed separately.  Not anaconda, homebrew or macports python.  Many other software packages have the same issue.  In Windows land there's a thing called "DLL Hell".

Comment: I am facing the same issue from QGIS installed from KyngChaos package. I installed both the GDAL Complete and QGIS packages but get this error when running processing commands that use the gdal scripts. Those scripts are present in /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs/

Comment: Good day everyone, I had the same issue and followed the workaround from the readme.txt. (By the way the path in there is "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.2/Programs:"). But still nothing works and I have this error message now: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/algs/gdal/GdalAlgorithm.py", line 115, in processAlgorithm
GdalUtils.runGdal(commands, feedback)
File "/Applications/QGIS3.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/alg

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is a known issue as documented on KyngChaos
https://www.kyngchaos.com/blog/2018/20180322_qgis_3.0.0-3

A workaround is available as follows

> Go to Settings ... Options... System ... Environment Enable "Use Custom Variables "
>
> First select "Prepend", under variable enter "PATH", under value enter
>
> "/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:"
>
> (all these without the quotes)

Restart QGIS and it should work.

Comment: As of 3.0.1, this is included in the Read Me.rtf. Seems to work (so far).

Comment: This solution worked perfectly on QGIS 3.4.10-Madeira, under iOS Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: This works as well William's QGIS3.8.3. Without this solution, William's 3.4 and 3.8 installations will not be working.

Comment: @spatialthoughts, thanks. I had the same issue and this fixed my issue with GDAL on my Mac 10.15.2 running QGIS 3.4 and 3.10. However, I'm having the same issue with other processing tools for Grass and Saga. Is there a similar custom variable required for each of these?

Comment: @Colin Here's the workaround for GRASS https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/32511#issuecomment-552190397 , but this issue was fixed and the latest mac installers for 3.10 works out of the box for me.