# QGIS gdal_translate: command not found

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, qgis-3

When I go to Raster -> Extraction -> Clip Raster by extent, I get the error "/bin/sh: gdal_translate: command not found ".  I am using QGIS version 3.0 on a MacBook Pro.

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Lots of people having issues using GDAL in QGIS 3. I'd go back to the 2.18 Long Term Release until 3 settles out. Also maybe report the error: https://qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/bugreporting.html#bugs-features-and-issues

Comment: do you have GDAL installed? if so which version?

Comment: In my **GNU/Linux Debian** it works without any problem because **gdal_translate** is in **/usr/bin** directory. It was not installed in your system with QGIS 3.

Comment: see the workaround in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276853/gdal-scripts-not-found-in-qgis-3-on-osx