# QGIS 3.4.4 Processing Tools not working on Mac

Tags: qgis-3

I'm running QGIS3.4.4 on a mac (OS:10.14.2). The Processing Tools don't appear to work.

I'm working through the examples in 'Learn QGIS -4th edition' from Packt> which uses the official qgis_sample_data for Alaska. So I assume the data and loading are clean. I've used Processing Tools successfully in earlier QGIS versions (currently 2.14), but can't get them working for 3.4.

The lastest failure is on 'Clip Raster by Mask Layer', reports similar problems to earlier failures - saying, 'layers not correctly generated'.

[image]

Comment: Is the output a temporary layer or have you tried saving it to disk by specifying a name? And if so, is the path very simple or does it contain special characters? I've had issues with some processing tools not accepting temp layers from time to time.

Comment: Hi @ChrisF, welcome to GIS.SE! The error says: `/bin/sh/: gdalwarp: command not found`. Check [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276853/gdal-scripts-not-found-in-qgis-3-on-osx).

Comment: Hi @GabrielDeLuca. Thanks for the link. I had the same issue and that information fixed my issue with GDAL on my Mac 10.15.2 running QGIS 3.4 and 3.10. However, I'm having the same issue with other processing tools for Grass and Saga. Is there a similar variable required for each of these?

Comment: @Colin, Hi, I have not idea. Maybe the following link helps you : https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/32511.