# Problems with some gdal functions in Mac version of QGIS3.4?

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal

This morning I have been trying to clip, extract, do anything with a DEM in V3.4 on a mac10.14.3 (it works fine on linux Debian).

I receive an error message in the dialog box - attached and the log messages indicates '/bin/sh: gdal_translate: command not found'

I installed Madeira (3.4) from the main site, not through Kyngchaos, and using python 3.6.x as instructed in the dmg file.

[image: log messages panel]

[image: error in dialog box.]

Comment: looks like it can't see gdal_translate

Comment: Yes that's the case, How can I make it see gdal_translate?

Comment: You need to edit your question - probably remove reference to tempDIR and add in how you installed qgis and gdal

Comment: See [GDAL scripts not found in QGIS 3 on OSX](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/277398/2581)

Comment: @gene: this has been rectified through an earlier build according to this linked post. Also I tried this workaround and still no joy. and finally, the url to kyngchaos is 404'ed.

Comment: In the Read Me.rtf file

Answer (score 0):

The content of the QGIS 3.6.pkg package is

[image]

The scripts are installed in `/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.4/Programs`

[image]

And in the Read Me.rtf file:

> External Program Paths
>   QGIS 3 does not find external tools needed for Processing.  Some configuration options are missing.  A workaround is to use QGIS custom variables.
>
> - Open QGIS Preferences → System.
> - Under the Environment section, turn on Use Custom Variables.
> - Add (+) a variable
> - Select Prepend from the Apply popup
> - Enter PATH for the variable
> - For the Value enter:
>     /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.4/Programs:
> - Quit QGIS 3 and start it again
>     NOTE: this may need to be updated when upgrading from a previous version of QGIS.

Comment: Thank you for this. I have tried this and it has not rectified the problem. No difference in the error messages.

Comment: I suspect this same problem may be preventing me using the Hotspot Analysis plugin for 3.x. QGIS seems to draw from earlier python install i.e. 2.7. Is this possible? and if so, how can I correct this?