# Error when reprojecting raster (warp) QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, gdalwarp

When trying to reproject a raster from degrees to meters in warp (QGIS) I receive the following error:

```
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Warp (reproject)' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'DATA_TYPE' : 0, 'EXTRA' : '', 'INPUT' : '/Users/annanilsson/Desktop/in_ref_annual.tif', 'MULTITHREADING' : False, 'NODATA' : None, 'OPTIONS' : '', 'OUTPUT' : '/var/folders/jv/g8xcbz2n4y109pdxsfr1hr080000gn/T/processing_387d8ccc215042b78b22f1546c4dd5c0/34324c65b826461a9a98f356bb1accdc/OUTPUT.tif', 'RESAMPLING' : 0, 'SOURCE_CRS' : None, 'TARGET_CRS' : QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:32635'), 'TARGET_EXTENT' : None, 'TARGET_EXTENT_CRS' : None, 'TARGET_RESOLUTION' : None }

GDAL command:
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:32635 -r near -of GTiff /Users/annanilsson/Desktop/in_ref_annual.tif /var/folders/jv/g8xcbz2n4y109pdxsfr1hr080000gn/T/processing_387d8ccc215042b78b22f1546c4dd5c0/34324c65b826461a9a98f356bb1accdc/OUTPUT.tif
GDAL command output:
/bin/sh: gdalwarp: command not found

Execution completed in 0.11 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': '/var/folders/jv/g8xcbz2n4y109pdxsfr1hr080000gn/T/processing_387d8ccc215042b78b22f1546c4dd5c0/34324c65b826461a9a98f356bb1accdc/OUTPUT.tif'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.<ul><li>/var/folders/jv/g8xcbz2n4y109pdxsfr1hr080000gn/T/processing_387d8ccc215042b78b22f1546c4dd5c0/34324c65b826461a9a98f356bb1accdc/OUTPUT.tif</li></ul>You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

Any suggestions on what I might have done wrong?

Comment: are you on OSX? see if e.g. [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276853/gdal-scripts-not-found-in-qgis-3-on-osx) might help. you can try to run the very same command (after `GDAL command:` in your log above) in terminal if you have GDAL installed globally.