# Using MERGE command in QGIS?

Tags: dem, merge

I am working on QGIS 3.4.9 with Mac OS Mojave 10.14.5
I have two DEM raster files and I would like to merge them. Unfortunately, an error occurs and I don't know what to do.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please capture both your command and error as text, and [Edit] the question to add them to the question body. All questions should always contain the exact error in a for that can be searched and be visible on all devices.

Comment: It is hard to tell, but maybe you can try to use the SAGA's "Mosaic raster layers" tool instead.

Comment: You might search Google on the error message gdal_merge.py: command not found.  That provided many possibilities including this one from stackexchange: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276853/gdal-scripts-not-found-in-qgis-3-on-osx