# Using QGIS with GDAL installed conda on Mac OSX

Tags: qgis, gdal

I used `conda` to install GDAL in a virtual environment in OSX 10.15 (Catalina). I have no problem running the GDAL scripts in terminal (such as `gdal_translate, gdalwarp`, etc).
I also installed QGIS (`3.14.16-Pi`). But I get an error when trying to run a QGIS command that calls GDAL.

For example, clipping a raster to a shape file using `Raster > Extraction > Clip by Mask Layer` yields the errors:

`/bin/sh: gdalwarp: command not found`

Following [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276853/gdal-scripts-not-found-in-qgis-3-on-osx) I prepended the path to gdal in QGIS: `Preferences > System > Environment`.  But the problem remains.

Is there some other QGIS parameter I need to set to get it find gdal?

Installing GDAL:

```
conda create -n gdal_env
conda activate gdal_env
conda install gdal

gdalinfo --version
GDAL 3.0.4, released 2020/01/28
```

Path to GDAL prepended in QGIS:

`/Users/MF/miniconda3/envs/gdal_env/bin`

Comment: I should have mentioned that I restarted QGIS after prepending the path