# Running GDAL processing tools from QGIS in conda environment

Tags: qgis, gdal, conda

I am trying to run `Polygonize (Raster to Vector)` from QGIS 3.18.3-Zürich inside a conda environment. When running the command, I encountered the following error.

> Process gdal_polygonize.bat failed to start. Either
> gdal_polygonize.bat is missing, or you may have insufficient
> permissions to run the program.

[image]

I am able to load gdal from Python

```
(geoenv) C:\Users\jaina>python
Python 3.8.12 (default, Oct 12 2021, 03:01:40) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from osgeo import gdal
>>>
```

Also, `gdalinfo` works fine. I tried adding gdal scripts directory to the `PATH`

```
C:\Users\jaina\.conda\envs\geoenv\Scripts
```

I also tried [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276853/gdal-scripts-not-found-in-qgis-3-on-osx/277398) answer to modify system settings in QGIS but it resulted in `no module SIP` error on starting QGIS and processing tool bar disappears.

```
/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.18.3/bin:
```

A similar question is unanswered [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/377191/using-qgis-with-gdal-installed-conda-on-mac-osx)

**EDIT**:

`Path to gdal_polygonize.bat`

```
C:\Users\jaina\.conda\envs\geoenv>dir /s gdal_polygonize.bat
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is 60CD-213A
File Not Found
```

Path to `gdal_polygonize.py`

```
C:\Users\jaina\.conda\envs\geoenv>dir /s gdal_polygonize.py

 Directory of C:\Users\jaina\.conda\envs\geoenv\Lib\site-packages\GDAL-3.3.2-py3.8-win-amd64.egg-info\scripts

16-10-2021  15:38               330 gdal_polygonize.py

 Directory of C:\Users\jaina\.conda\envs\geoenv\Lib\site-packages\osgeo_utils

01-10-2021  22:52             7,525 gdal_polygonize.py

 Directory of C:\Users\jaina\.conda\envs\geoenv\Scripts

16-10-2021  15:38               210 gdal_polygonize.py
```

All paths for conda environment

```
(geoenv) C:\Users\jaina>set PATH
Path=C:\Users\jaina\.conda\envs\geoenv;C:\Users\jaina\.conda\envs\geoenv\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\jaina\.conda\envs\geoenv\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\jaina\.conda\envs\geoenv\Library\bin;C:\Users\jaina\.conda\envs\geoenv\Scripts;C:\Users\jaina\.conda\envs\geoenv\bin;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\condabin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Git LFS;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Users\jaina\.conda\envs\geoenv\Scripts;C:\Users\jaina\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;.
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
```

Comment: What happens with the Tool? https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/training_manual/complete_analysis/raster_to_vector.html

Comment: Sorry did not get the question you asked? Is there something I should be take away from the docs you linked?

Comment: Did you search where `gdal_polygonize.bat` is located on your computer using files search? Where is it? Do you have one file, more? Give us the list of paths.

Comment: @ThomasG77 I edited the question to add paths. `gdal_polygonize.bat` is not present inside my environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a file `$CONDA_PREFIX/bin/gdal_polygonize.bat` with your text editor. In your case, it should be `C:\Users\jaina\.conda\envs\geoenv\bin\gdal_polygonize.bat`

Then, within the file, put the following

```
@echo off
%CONDA_PYTHON_EXE% "%CONDA_PREFIX%/lib/python3.8/site-packages/osgeo_utils/gdal_polygonize.py" %*
```

I do not know why but no `.bat` files were generated when installing conda. You may open an issue at https://github.com/conda-forge/qgis-feedstock/issues

Comment: Since I did not have bin folder, I had to create one. Inside that I created that file with modified code since there was no lib and python3.8 dir. 
`@echo off
%CONDA_PYTHON_EXE% "%CONDA_PREFIX%/Lib/site-packages/osgeo_utils/gdal_polygonize.py" %*`
After that I tried running the processing tool, and now it shows that module `osgeo does not exists` . It is not reading the correct python execution file. Could this occur as I installed all these packages using miniconda? Attaching a photo https://i.imgur.com/aFuIz3o.png